# How can i detect maven 2 jar dependencies?

Tags: java, maven-2, dependencies

I added some jars as dependencies in `pom.xml`, but it seems that some of them are useless because those jars were already downloaded using dependencies mechanism...

Is there a way to see those "built-in" dependencies, so that I could add only the needed dependencies in my pom.xml?

For example if I add a hibernate dependency in pom.xml one for cglib is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that - list every dependency of *your* code, but not of the libraries you use; Maven will do its transitive dependency thing and take care of them.

Comment: But conversely, if your code directly depends on some library, then relying on transitive dependencies for that library (via some other dependency) potentially makes your dependencies fragile.

Comment: @Stephen C: Exactly, that's why I dislike maven.

Comment: You can control transitive dependencies as finely as you want. This is a non issue.

Comment: The fragility only comes into play if you depend on snapshots or if you change your dependencies.  And it is generally easy to fix.  So yes this is mostly a "style" issue.

Comment: the task of managing transitive dependencies won't go away by not using maven. With maven at least you avoid having jars with unknown version that you don't know if you still need or not.

Answer (score 2):

you can run `mvn dependency:tree` to get the whole tree including the transient dependencies that get included in your project. 
There you can start looking

Hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

First, check out [Transitive Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies):

> Transitive dependencies are a new
>   feature in Maven 2.0. This allows you
>   to avoid needing to discover and
>   specify the libraries that your own
>   dependencies require, and including
>   them automatically.

Then, a good dependency analyzer will help...

The **mvn** command-line is your first aid:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Sometimes you have to figure out where the version numbers came from (See also: [Dependency Management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management)).  Here you'll have to unveil the parent relationships, and the 'effective-pom' command can help with that:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

Tool support is helpful as well...

**m2eclipse** has a [Dependency Tree tab](https://www.sonatype.com/ebooks#fig-eclipse-pom-editor-dependencies) that shows how the different hierarchies collapse::

[alt text http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/figs/web/eclipse_pom-editor-depend-tree.png](http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/figs/web/eclipse_pom-editor-depend-tree.png)

**IntelliJ** has another [interesting view that lets you detect the conflicts](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/05/maven-dependencies-diagram/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20jetbrains_intellijidea%20(JetBrains%20IntelliJ%20IDEA%20Blog)):

[image]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/3.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse then you are see a visual dependency tree which is automatically generated. While adding a dependency if you do not want it to automatically pull some transitive dependencies use the exclusions tag like so

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

There are some known conflicts when using certain versions of hibernate and AOP due to cglib.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to see those "built-in" dependencies, so that I could add only the needed dependencies in my pom.xml?

There are no *built-in* dependencies. However, when declaring a dependency on a given artifact, Maven will also retrieve the dependencies of this dependency, transitively. Such dependencies are called [3.4.4. Transitive Dependencies](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-transitive.html):

> A transitive dependency is a dependency of a dependency. If `project-a` depends on `project-b`, which in turn depends on `project-c`, then `project-c` is considered a transitive dependency of `project-a`. If `project-c` depended on `project-d`, then `project-d` would also be considered a transitive dependency of `project-a`.

So if you need a dependency in your project, just declare it (and the dependencies of this dependency will come transitively).

To visualize the dependency tree of a project, the best tool is `mvn dependency:tree` (or any fronted offered by your favorite IDE). This is a must use tool to analyze your dependencies and check them for proper convergence and potential conflicts resulting in expected version being used.

> For example if I add a hibernate dependency in pom.xml one for cglib is not needed.

Actually, this is a bad example, cglib is an [***optional***](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) dependency of Hibernate Core which declares in its `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-cglib-repack</artifactId>
  <version>2.1_3</version>
  <optional>true</optional><!-- think of it as "excluded by default" -->
</dependency>
```

Hibernate gives you the choice between javassist and cglib, it's up to you to decide which one to use and to declare it explicitly, hence the *optional* status.

#### See also

- [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)
- The whole section [3.4. Project Dependencies](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html) in the Maven Reference Guide